# Operator() as a subscript for a Matrix class

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading

By following this site [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/matrix-subscript-op.html) I have overloaded an operator() for my Matrix class. This is my class:

```
class Matrix
{
    public:
    inline float& operator() (unsigned row, unsigned col)
    {
        return m[row][col];
    }

    private:
    float m[4][4];
};
```

now I can use it in main function like this:

```
int main()
{
    Matrix matrix;
    std::cout << matrix(2,2);
}
```

but now I want to use it with the pointer like this:

```
int main()
{
    Matrix matrix;
    Matrix* pointer = &matrix;
    std::cout << pointer(2,2);
}
```

and compilator tells that pointer can not be used as a function. Is there any solution?

Comment: Also provide 'inline const float & operator()' for being able to call from const matrix objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll either need to dereference it:

```
(*pointer)(2,2)
```

Or you'll need to call the operator by its full name:

```
pointer->operator()(2,2)
```